# iOS app giving low memory warnings with 350MB size

Tags: ipad, ios6, automatic-ref-counting, nsbundle

I have developed one iPad application targeting for iOS6 and using ARC. Application size is 350 MB due to many images, audio & video files in the bundle. As this app will work locally I am storing the content in application' main bundle. How to reduce bundle size in my current situation ?

And when app launches I am receiving 'Low memory warnings'. Till now I am not seeing app crashing for this but is it something I need to consider ?

Answer (score 1):

Your app is not crashing doesn't mean you should neglect memory warnings I feel.

Below is what the Apple docs say:

> When the system dispatches a low-memory warning to your app, respond immediately. iOS notifies all running apps whenever the amount of free memory dips below a safe threshold. (It does not notify suspended apps.) If your app receives this warning, it must free up as much memory as possible. The best way to do this is to remove strong references to caches, image objects, and other data objects that can be recreated later.

So make sure you reduce memory footprint of your application, do a strict code review which may help you.

Comment: Thanks vinayaka.. This will help upto some extent regarding 'Low memory warnings' so I given one up vote. How can i reduce bundle size or app size ? Anybody else plz do answer my query